# How to skew a video recorded using a camera in blender compositor or video editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, distort

I want to know how to skew a video in blender compositor or in the video editor. I have a video that had been stabilized in blender VFX. Now the movie is super smooth but now the rolling shutter effect is more apparent and it's making the video hard to watch (it's a panning video of a plane flying across). My goal is to use skewing to counter the rolling shutter artifacts. Ie. if the rolling shutter makes the video skew left, I'll counter it by adding skewing to right. So any help would be really appreciated!

[image: My idea]